# connect apache druid with prometheus and druid-exporter

Tags: prometheus, druid

I have a Apache Druid database and I want to monitor Apache Druid database with Prometheus.
I research and found Druid Exporter support Prometheus collect metrics from Apache Druid
and I found document as below:
https://github.com/opstree/druid-exporter

I install everything in docker.

---

Follow guideline, I set in file common.runtime.properties of druid:

```
> druid_emitter_http_recipientBaseUrl=http://<druid_exporter_url>:<druid_exporter_port>/druid
> druid_emitter=http
```

Replace

```
http://<druid_exporter_url>:<druid_exporter_port>/druid
```

With

```
http://druid.opstreelabs.in:9091/druid
```

After that I run druid-exporter with command:

```
docker run -itd --name druid-exporter -p 9091:9091 -e DRUID_URL="http://druid.opstreelabs.in" -e PORT="9091" opstree/druid-exporter:v0.10
```

I finally, I edit prometheus.yml file with:

```
- job_name: 'druid'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9091']
```

After run prometheus on port 9090, I received targets at bellow:
[image]

Please help me to resolve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think that all the steps you ran are fine but seems that the exporter is not running normally (this often happens when the 9091 port is being used elsewhere).

Anyway, you should check the logs via:

```
docker logs -f druid-exporter
```

and then see what happened.

---

If the exporter is executed normally, you can see the following logs.

```
time="2021-08-25T03:35:52Z" level=info msg="Druid exporter started listening on: 9091"
time="2021-08-25T03:35:52Z" level=info msg="Metrics endpoint - http://0.0.0.0:9091/metrics"
time="2021-08-25T03:35:52Z" level=info msg="Druid emitter endpoint - http://0.0.0.0:9091/druid"
```